# Populate an NSTokenField with tokens from a container of objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, tags, nstokenfield

I have an NSTableView and an NSTokenField in a window.  I have implemented the following delegate methods:

```
tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:
tokenField:representedObjectForEditingString:
tokenField:displayStringForRepresentedObject:
```

I want to make it so that when a row is selected in it, the NSTokenField gets populated with the tags that are contained in an NSMutableSet of the row object.  How do I populate an NSTokenField with tokens if I have a container of the objects that they represent (and therefore the strings that need to be made into tokens)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  In the code below ms is an NSMutableSet that contains my objects.

```
        //set the token field
        NSMutableArray *ma = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (MyClass *anObject in ms){
            [ma addObject:anObject];
        }

        //sort the array
        NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"title" ascending: YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sorter, nil];

        [ma sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
        [tokenField setObjectValue:ma];
```

The key is the last line: **[tokenField setObjectValue:ma];**